# windows phone loading data from MainViewModel

Tags: windows-phone-7

Noob question probably.
I am developing a mvm wp7 app where the map shows pushpins of salons. The database is retrieved from a link.

The problem i am struggling with is that the observable collection data  is not being loaded from the App._ViewModel (where the json serializer parses the database and works fine). On debugging the app shows a plain map and thats all. On returning a string attribute from the database causes a break on that code. i tried messagebox as well to show the string, still crashes.

Heres the code:

mainviewmodel.cs

> public class MainViewModel
>       {
>           public bool IsDataLoaded { get; private set; }
>
> ```
>     public ObservableCollection<SalonViewModel> SalonCollection { get; private set; }
>
>
>     public MainViewModel()
>     {
>         IsDataLoaded = false; 
>     }
>
>     public ObservableCollection<SalonViewModel> LoadData()
>     {
>         SalonCollection = new ObservableCollection<SalonViewModel>();
>         var wednesday = new Uri("http://blehbleh.txt");
>         WebClient wc = new WebClient();
>         wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenReadCompleted);
>         wc.OpenReadAsync(wednesday);
>
>         return SalonCollection;
>     }
>
>     public void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
>     { 
>         try
>         { 
>             DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<SalonViewModel>));
>             ObservableCollection<SalonViewModel> list = serializer.ReadObject(e.Result) as ObservableCollection<SalonViewModel>;
>
>             foreach (SalonViewModel b in list)
>             { 
>                SalonCollection.Add(new SalonViewModel { sid=b.sid,sname=b.sname,sgeo_lat=b.sgeo_lat,sgeo_lon=b.sgeo_lon, 
>
>             }
>
>             this.IsDataLoaded = true;
>
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             //throw ex;
>             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
>         }
>     }
> ```

The App.cs

> public partial class App : Application
>       {
>
> ```
>     private static MainViewModel viewModel;
>
>     public static MainViewModel _viewModel
>     { 
>         get
>         {
>             if (viewModel == null)
>             {
>                 viewModel = new MainViewModel();
>             }
>
>             return viewModel;
>         }
>     }
>
>     void LoadData()
>     {
>         if (!_viewModel.IsDataLoaded)
>         {
>             _viewModel.LoadData();
>         }
>     }
> ```
>
> etc

Heres the mappage.cs

> private void salon_map_Loaded (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>                {
>
> ```
>              foreach (SalonViewModel Salon in App._viewModel.LoadData)
>              {
>                  MessageBox.Show(Salon.sname);
>                  Pushpin p = new Pushpin();
>                  p.Content = Salon.sname + System.Environment.NewLine + "Rate: "; 
>                  Layer.AddChild(p, new GeoCoordinate(Salon.sgeo_lon, Salon.sgeo_lat)); 
>              }
>
>              Map1.Children.Add(Layer); 
>
>          }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `MainViewModel` `LoadData` function, `OpenReadAsync()` is an asynchronous function, and thus returning `SalonCollection` on the next line will return an empty `ObservableCollection`, since the callback function `wc_OpenReadCompleted` has not run yet.

Also, the reason the `MessageBox.Show` crashes is because you are attempting to call a UI function on a non-UI thread (solution to that here: [Dispatcher.Invoke() on Windows Phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004252/dispatcher-invoke-on-windows-phone-7))

Instead of returning the `ObservableCollection` and manually adding children to the map from that, try binding a `MapItemsControl` layer of the `Map` to the `ObservableCollection` of your view model. There's a decent example of doing that here: [Binding Pushpins to Bing Maps in Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968424/binding-pushpins-to-bing-maps-in-windows-phone)